# How many ways to cover a N×N chessboard with white and black boxes by some restrictions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, covering, colorings

Suppose we have a N×N chessboard and the boxes ■, □.

We should cover the chessboard with those boxes but there can not have the 2×2 square $\scriptstyle{\begin{array}{cc}\square&\square\\
\square&\square\end{array}}$
on the chessboard.

Can we calculate the ways to cover the chessboard?

Furthermore, 
(1) if we connect the up(left) boundary and the down(right) boundary together, which means the up(left) and down(right) boundary form a 2×N(N×2) rectangle and it should not have the 2×2 square
 $\scriptstyle{\begin{array}{cc}\square&\square\\
\square&\square\end{array}}$
too.
Can we calculate the ways?

(2) if we have k black boxes, with the (1) chessboard, can we calculate the ways?

Comment: The first one is http://oeis.org/A139810 which has no formula or other information. I doubt that a simple formula exists, but it would be quite interesting to know what the asymptotic behaviour is.

Comment: a closed-form expression for case 1 is given by Simon Cowell https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03580 ; references for upper and lower bounds are also given.

Comment: the Cowell expression is given as Mathematica code in http://oeis.org/A255936

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  About $3^n$ operations if I understand it.

Comment: Thank you @CarloBeenakker for your edit and comments, it helps me understand the problem deeply.

Comment: Thank you @BrendanMcKay for your comment,  it's kinda sad to know that there has no simple formula of the problem. the upper and lower bounds are given in [KKP93](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=159819) and [SL90](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=103023&tag=1).

Comment: The link [KKP93] is wrong and I relink it here [KKP93](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=273602)